# Lower the exponent in $\hat{h}^2$

Tags: math-mode, positioning, mathjax

In Mathjax, `h^2 \hat{h}^2 (\hat{h})^2` results in

[image: rendered latex showing the problem]

I want the middle block, but with `2` lower.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{..}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: When I use `$h^2 \hat{h}^2 (\hat{h})^2$` I get the exponents (i.e., the 2s) at the same level.

Comment: I'm using MathJax, so that's all of my code.  Is that acceptable here?

Comment: I don't use mathjax much, but I bet `\hat{h}{}^2` would work.

Comment: @mrc: Write up an answer. Perhaps use [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lwjuh.png); tested on [math.se]. ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about MathJax. While MathJax shares its syntax with TeX/LaTeX its engine is different

Comment: @Guido Is this question really off-topic? We have [Mathjax] tag, and the description http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/mathjax/info suggests asking "installation, running, and debugging" questions at StackOverflow, but does not suggest asking syntax-related questions at StackOverflow. If it is off-topic, should we suggest moving it to SO?

Comment: @mrc Yes: the output of `\hat{h}^2` in TeX is correct, exactly as if the hat weren't there; so the question is just how to fix the placement with MathJax and this is beyond the scope of this site, because it depends on the implementation of MathJax.